# Selecting range based on cells and return the adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

Greeting,
I am trying to find a function formula or a vba macro to solve this problem. Appreciate your support and help in this matter.
I have a list in column C as you can see and I would like to get a specific cell between a range of data based on range I am selecting in this case the numbers in column F. For example:
I would like to select the cells between 1000 and 2000 then get the specific cell called “ Apple” which is in G2 an return the adjacent cell using offsets formula to get D4 “ Red” 
The solution would be like the right table where all data are filled based on the range specified.
Thank you in your advance for your support.
[image]d

Comment: What do you mean with "I select" or "Get"? Show an example of a real usage of the wanted code along with your attempts at writing it

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't as dynamic as it could be but it works if the columns for the table are static.

```
Dim row As Byte, lastRow As Byte
Dim currentNumber As Long
Dim currentText As String

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastRow
        If Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(row, 2))) Then
            If (IsNumeric(.Cells(row, 2))) Then
                currentNumber = .Cells(row, 2)
            ElseIf (Len(.Cells(row, 2) > 0)) Then
                currentText = .Cells(row, 2)
                Select Case currentNumber
                    Case 1000
                        If StrComp(currentText, "Apple", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(3, 6) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Banana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(3, 7) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Orange", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(3, 8) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(3, 9) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Car", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(3, 10) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                    Case 2000
                        If StrComp(currentText, "Apple", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(4, 6) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Banana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(4, 7) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Orange", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(4, 8) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(4, 9) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Car", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(4, 10) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                    Case 5000
                        If StrComp(currentText, "Apple", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(5, 6) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Banana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(5, 7) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Orange", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(5, 8) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(5, 9) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Car", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(5, 10) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                    Case 7000
                        If StrComp(currentText, "Apple", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(6, 6) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Banana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(6, 7) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Orange", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(6, 8) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(6, 9) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Car", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(6, 10) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                    Case 10000
                        If StrComp(currentText, "Apple", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(7, 6) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Banana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(7, 7) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Orange", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(7, 8) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(7, 9) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        ElseIf StrComp(currentText, "Car", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Cells(7, 10) = .Cells(row, 2).Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next row
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have a lot of data and I cannot write every individual data manually .